# PHP Regex match sentence with word anytime when it's not a followed by another word

Tags: php, regex

Below is the array of sentences I have

```
$strings = [ 
  "I want to match docs with a word New", 
  "But I don't want to match docs with a phrase New York", 
  "However I still want to match docs with a word New which has a phrase New York", 
  "For example let's say there's a New restaraunt in New York and I want this doc to be matched."
]
```

I want to match the above sentences with word **`new`** string in it. But I don't want match the sentence when **`new`** is followed by **`york`**. I'd like to be able to match any word `A` that isn't prepended/followed by word `B` within some small word distance `N`. Not immediate next to `A'.

How can I achieve expected result using regex?

Comment: Use negative lookahead [`(?!)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression with a negative lookahead should do the trick (visit [this link](https://regex101.com/r/1fIhrK/1) for a working demo):

```
.*[Nn]ew(?! [Yy]ork).*
```

On the point of view of the `PHP` implementation, you can use the [preg_match function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) as follows:

```
$strings = [ 
    "I want to match docs with a word New", 
    "But I don't want to match docs with a phrase New York", 
    "However I still want to match docs with a word New which has a phrase New York", 
    "For example let's say there's a New restaraunt in New York and I want this doc to be matched."
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_match('/.*new(?! york).*/i', $string)."\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
1 -> Match
0 -> Discarded
1 -> Match
1 -> Match
```

Comment: Wouldn't this perform better without the wildcards at the sides? Since you're only checking the text is present, you don't want to match everything. [`.*new(?! york).*`, 212 steps](https://regex101.com/r/1fIhrK/2) vs [`new(?! york)` 64 steps](https://regex101.com/r/1fIhrK/3). Just a thought, +1.

Comment: You are totally right! Thanks for pointing it out! This changes a little bit the way the matches must be handled though.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte well that's just magic now. Thanks for the feedback!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/(new[^ ?york])|(a[^b])/gi
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tGvINX/3/)